# Is my simpler proof of $d(f, G^\perp) = \sup_{x \in G, |x| \le 1} \langle f, x \rangle$ correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I'm reading *Theorem 2.16* in Brezis' book of Functional Analysis. The author uses Fenchel-Rockafellar's theorem to derive below result.

> Let $G$ be a closed subspace of a Banach space $(E, | \cdot |)$ and $G^\perp := \{f \in E^* \mid \langle f, x \rangle =0, \forall x\in G \}$. Then $G^\perp$ is a closed subspace of $(E^*, \| \cdot \|)$ with $\|f\| := \sup_{x\in E, |x| \le 1} \langle f, x \rangle$. We define $d(f, G^\perp) := \inf_{h \in G^\perp} \|f-h\|$ for all $f \in E^\star$. Then $$d(f, G^\perp) = \sup_{x \in G, |x| \le 1} \langle f, x \rangle.$$

I try to give it a more elementary proof. Could you have a check on my attempt? It seems from my proof that the result still holds in case $E$ is not complete and $G$ is not closed.

**My attempt:**

Let $C$ be the right hand side. First, we have $$\begin{aligned}
d(f, G^\perp) ={}& \inf_{h \in G^\perp} \sup_{x\in E, |x| \le 1} \langle f - h, x \rangle \\
\ge {}& \inf_{h \in G^\perp} \sup_{x\in G, |x| \le 1} \langle f - h, x \rangle \\
={} & C. \\
\end{aligned}$$

Let $f_G := f_{\restriction G}$. Then $f_G \in G^\star$ and  $\|f_G\| = C$. By Hahn-Banach theorem, there is an extension $\tilde f_{G} \in E^\star$ of $f_G$ such that $\|\tilde f_{G}\| = C$. It follows that $$\begin{aligned}
d(f, G^\perp) ={}& \inf_{h \in G^\perp} \sup_{x\in E, |x| \le 1} \langle f - h, x \rangle \\
\le {}& \sup_{x\in E, |x| \le 1} \langle \tilde f_{G}, x \rangle \\
={} & C. \\
\end{aligned}$$

This completes the proof.